# Audio só iniciar quando eu chegar em determinada div

Tags: javascript, html5, html5-audio

Estou desenvolvendo uma página que em apenas determinados textos tem áudio. Quero fazer com que o áudio do texto só comece a tocar quando eu chegar no texto. Segue mais ou menos como eu queria. (Não tenho muito conhecimento em javascript, se puderem me dá um help com essa questão.)

```
<audio src="audio/2.mp3" autoplay></audio>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum animi nobis voluptates aspernatur, impedit molestiae reiciendis. Nisi necessitatibus magnam voluptatem eaque, ut ullam et, sunt aperiam voluptatibus alias, ipsa nesciunt.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum animi nobis voluptates aspernatur, impedit molestiae reiciendis. Nisi necessitatibus magnam voluptatem eaque, ut ullam et, sunt aperiam voluptatibus alias, ipsa nesciunt.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum animi nobis voluptates aspernatur, impedit molestiae reiciendis. Nisi necessitatibus magnam voluptatem eaque, ut ullam et, sunt aperiam voluptatibus alias, ipsa nesciunt.</p>
<audio src="audio/2.mp3" autoplay></audio>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum animi nobis voluptates aspernatur, impedit molestiae reiciendis. Nisi necessitatibus magnam voluptatem eaque, ut ullam et, sunt aperiam voluptatibus alias, ipsa nesciunt.</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa definir uma *Classe* ou um *id* para a *div* que quer que inicie o áudio.

```
  <audio id = "audioDiv" src="audio/2.mp3"></audio>
```

**Remova o AutoPlay do seu elemento**

No Javascript você irá pegar essa classe ou id:

```
   //Se você colocar id
   audio = document.GetElementById("audioDiv")
```

ou

```
  //Se você colocar class
   audio = document.GetElementsByClassName("audioDiv")
```

Então você colocará essa condição em baixo:

```
  if (document.documentElement.scrollTop >= audio.offsetTop) {

    audio.play()

   }
```

Resultado do código testável:

```
    audio = document.GetElementById("audioDiv")
    onscroll = function()
    {
       if (document.documentElement.scrollTop <= audio.offsetTop) {

       audio.play();
       console.log("ligado")

    }else if (document.documentElement.scrollTop >= audio.offsetTop){

       audio.pause();
       console.log("desligado")
    }
  }
```

Explicando o código e como aplicar a sua situação:

A variavel *Audio* receberá o elemento que contém a mídia. O *if* irá verificar se a pagina no navegador estará numa posição menor que a posição do elemento Audio.

Você pode mudar o operador *>=*  no *if* para obter outros resultados, como, por exemplo, mudar para *<*, que iniciará o audio quando o usuário passar por ele. Ai vai da sua necessidade.

A função *onscroll* irá fazer reproduzir o código toda vez que a pagina se mover. Ou seja, sempre que alguém rolar a pagina.

**Observação sobre *Class*:**

Se você for buscar o elemento pela Classe no javascript, ao final da linha de código você precisa definir um index para o elemento especifico, senão ele cria uma lista com **todas as Classes** existentes com o mesmo nome.

Ficará assim:

```
audio = document.getElementByClassName("audioDiv").item(0);
```

O 0 (zero) representa o primeiro elemento com a classe do nome audioDiv.